# How to access 2 cpp vectors with alternating indexes?

Tags: c++

How can I improve this code, so I could use iterator rather than index access?

The current implementation is not safe, because i might access the vector `a` out of bound, of course I could check the vector size first before calling `at` method, but I would love to know a better code, like using `for_each` or other modern cpp or lambda expression?

```
std::vector<int> a = { 1, 2, 3 };
std::vector<int> b = { 2, 1 };
std::vector<double> result;

for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++) {
    int current = a.at(i);
    int next = a.at(i + 1);

    double average = (current + next) / static_cast<double>(b.at(i));
    result.push_back(average);
}
```

Comment: Note that you're doing integer division: if `current = 1`, `next = 2`, `b.at(i) = 2`, then `average` ends up as `1`, not `1.5`.

Comment: thanks for pointing up, this is a just a simple example i am trying to illustrate to access 2 vectors with different indexes

Comment: Using iterators does not magically make you code safe. IMO, using an index variable is fine, too. However, since you use `at()` without a try-catch-block, you migh as well just use the normal array index operator, or consider wrapping it in a try-catch-block (which really should be unnecessary if your index logic is right).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing algorithms in terms of iterators is most stl-like and will result in efficient code.

It also has the advantage of describing the algorithm, rather than the containers, so it is versatile.

```
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

template<class Iter1, class Iter2, class OutIter>
void compute_splits(Iter1 first1, Iter1 last1,
                    Iter2 first2, Iter2 last2,
                    OutIter dest) {
    using t1 = typename std::iterator_traits<Iter1>::value_type;
    using t2 = typename std::iterator_traits<Iter2>::value_type;
    using tt = std::common_type_t<t1, t2>;

    // check preconditions
    auto valid = std::distance(first1, last1) == (1 + std::distance(first2, last2));
    assert(valid);

    while (first2 != last2) {
        tt tot = *first1 + *std::next(first1);
        tot /= *first2;
        *dest = tot;
        ++first1;
        ++first2;
        ++dest;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a = {1, 2, 3};
    std::vector<double> b = {2, 1};
    std::vector<double> result;

    compute_splits(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), std::back_inserter(result));

    std::copy(result.begin(), result.end(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, ", "));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

expected output:

```
1.5, 5,
```

Comment: thanks! this is a beautiful code and what i am looking for! ;)

Answer (score 1):

IMO this is the clearest way of doing that, and it doesn't get much faster than this*:

```
assert(a.size() == b.size() + 1);

for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); ++i) {
    result.push_back((a[i] + a[i + 1]) / static_cast<double>(b[i]));
}
```

This is completely safe because the assert makes sure the indices are valid.

If you need to validate the vector lengths in release mode as well, just switch the `assert` to some `if` check.

<sub>* (you can move the `b.size()` out of the loop and preallocate `result` but that's about it)</sub>